# No matching function for emplace upon adding a pair with std::hash

Tags: c++

I am using a pair as a key with `std::hash`, but running into an error upon `emplace()` where it can't match the function. Nothing stands out to me by just looking at it. Anyone?

> error: no matching member function for call to 'emplace'

```
class A
{
    using Pair = std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>;
    using MsrPairHash = std::hash<Pair>;
    std::unordered_map<Pair, std::shared_ptr<A>, MsrPairHash> mp;

public:
    void foo(std::string_view a, std::string_view b, std::shared_ptr<A> ptr)
    {
        mp.emplace({a, b}, std::move(ptr));
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `std::make_pair(a,b)` instead of `{a, b}`?

Comment: Side-note: It's kinda dangerous to have `std::string_view` provided by the caller as part of the key in a `std::unordered_map`; you have no idea what the lifetime of the strings underlying those views is, so you're requiring every caller to ensure the strings being viewed live as long as the views remain in the `unordered_map`. It's *much* safer to use owning `std::string`s for the keys, even if there is a small cost to make the copies.

Comment: @ShadowRanger interesting. is my understanding correct? https://godbolt.org/z/9Pxxa6aMf

Comment: @xyf: That one is probably safe, simply because string literals are typically stored in the read-only data section that lives the life of the program (it's *probably* not guaranteed by the standard, but it's safe in practice). It's when the `string_view`s view something that's not a string literal (e.g. any `std::string` that expires) that you'd have the problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger [String literals are guaranteed to live forever!](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#9)

Comment: @HTNW: Thanks. :-) Doesn't change the fact that an arbitrary `string_view` can't be trusted to live forever, but good to know.

Comment: @ShadowRanger perhaps an example shall help if my example doesn't demonstrate the stuff that could go wrong with `string_view`